# How to stop an extra trailing newline character?

Tags: python, newline

This is my code:

```
line = 'hi'
while line != '':
    line = input('Sentence: ')
    if '!' in line:
        if list(line)[0] == '!':
            reversed_text = ''
            last_index = len(line) - 1
            for i in range(last_index, -1, -1):
                reversed_text += line[i]
            print(reversed_text)
        else:
            print(line)
    else:
        print(line)
```

It seems to be adding an extra blank line when the user inputs nothing, and I'm not sure how to stop it. Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Have you [searched for an answer](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=python+print+without+newline)? This question is quite common.

Answer (score -1):

basically the `newline` is a result of your `print` printing an empty `line`. Take this code for example:

```
>>> a = input()    # user presses enter (blank line)
>>> a
''
>>> print(a)
                   # a newline introduced by `print` function
>>>
```

> we can however override this default behavior of print
>   print as the form [print([object, ...][, sep=' '][, end='\n'][, file=sys.stdout])](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/functions.html#print))

```
>>> a = ''
>>> print(a, end='')
>>>
```

To sum up, all you need to do in your code is, replace `print(<somevalue>)` with `print(<somevalue>, end='')`